# How to mount the Mac hard disk in Ubuntu booted from USB drive?

Tags: hard-drive, mac, mount

My Mac OSX is down, but the data on the hard disk is important to me. I boot the Mac from USB drive, in which Ubuntu is installed. How can I mount the Mac hard disk and get the data out of it?

I tried to use the command `sudo fdisk -l` to check the Mac hard drive, and then use `sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt/xxx` to mount the disk to `/mnt/xxx`, but it failed with the following system message:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Comment: Is the problem solved? If not, maybe you should mount a partition, not the whole disk – like `/dev/sda1` instead of `/dev/sda`.

Answer (score 1):

You need hfsprogs:

`sudo apt-get install hfsprogs`

Then:

`sudo mount -t hfsplus -o ro /dev/sda /mnt/xxx`

Comment: Hi Gala, thank you so much for your kindly reply.